# getUrl returning wrong url after site move to subdomain

Tags: siteurl

I just moved my old craft site to a subdomain. I changed it in the general settings, in the config/general.php file and in the .env file.

Everything works except for `.getUrl()`. This still returns the old domain and therefore no pictures are loading. Here is my example: https://historie.christlicher-gesundheitskongress.de/

Where does the `.getUrl()` come from?

Comment: Check your Settings → Assets → _your volume_ → Base URL

Answer (score 1):

Oil was right. For images you need to change your baseUrl at Settings → Assets → *your volume* → Base URL